# Error trying to create mssql layer in geoserver

Tags: geoserver, sql-server

with mssql 2008 and the latest geoserver with the mssql store plugin, I can create a dbo connection with a mssql database and list the tables. When I try to create a layer with one of the tables which has a "GEOM" field in the format POINT (3550951.71343219 5889701.66379654) I always get the same error when saving the layer...

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error occured calculating bounds for PUZZLE_LAYERVIEW_2 at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.getBounds(JDBCDataStore.java:1258)

What is the problem with the bounds? I have entered the correct EPSG code = EPSG:31467. Is the problem really with the bounds or with mssql geometries? An sql query layer works ok in ArcGIS.